# printState is not working

Tags: amp-html

Using it in console? Error. Using it as a function in the document? Error. Makes no sense. Why? How is it even possible to view the state? I'm using Laravel 4.2 in case you are wondering about the rest of the stuff, it's contained within the master template. This is the code for my page.

```
@extends('Templates.master')

@section('page-css')
    <style>

        .option-list {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vh;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            position: absolute;
        }

        .option-list.active {
            display: block;
        }

        .option-list.inactive {
            display: none;
        }

    </style>
@stop

@section('amp-component-scripts')
    <script async custom-element="amp-selector" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-selector-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
@stop

@section('html-content')

    <div class="option-list inactive" [class]="'option-list' + ' ' + myState.optionList.status">
        <amp-selector layout="container">
            <div option="1">opt 1</div>
            <div option="2">opt 2</div>
            <div option="3">opt 3</div>
            <div option="4">opt 4</div>
        </amp-selector>
    </div>

    <amp-state id="myState">
        <script type="application/json">
        {
            "optionList":{
                "status":"inactive",
                "options":[
                    {
                        "name":"option1",
                        "icon":"icon1"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"option2",
                        "icon":"icon2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
        </script>
    </amp-state>

    <button on="tap:AMP.setState({ optionList : { status : 'active' } })">press me plssss</button>

    <p [text]="myState.optionList.status">inactive</p>


@stop
```

Comment: reading this [github forum](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/8719), i think this feature is yet in the works.

Answer (score 1):

`AMP.printState()` currently works from the console. However, you need to add `#development=1` to the URL **and reload the page** for it to take effect, since the debugging is only enabled when `#development=1` is present on the URL when the page is loaded. Adding it once the page has been loaded doesn't enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/8876) issue.
It seems it was only enabled on localhost, can you try on localhost as well?